# Signal Handling on Linux when using Java/JNI

Tags: java, c++, linux, java-native-interface, signals

I work on an embedded system running on Wind River Linux.

It is a mix of Java and C++ with some JNI for communication between technologies.

We have build custom error handling so that in the event of any unexpected errors we generate backtraces and other information to help us determine the problem.

This error handling is always done by a C++ component that all other components must register with (so that the appropriate signals handlers can be installed).

So in the case of a Java component we use JNI to communicate with the C++ error hander.

Our test program uses 35 different scenario's to test all the various types of errors (out of memory, unhandled exceptions, access violations stackoverflows, etc) This is done for both a single main thread case and background threads.

All tests work properly with the exception of a Stackoverflow caused in a JNI main thread and background thread.

On Linux a Stackoverflow should generate a SIGSEGV and the installed sigaction  should be invoked.  But instead we are simply terminating, i.e. the handler does not get called.

If instead of generating a stackoverflow, we directly cause a SIGSEGV (signal 11), our signal handler does get invoked properly.

Note that we also do a LD_PRELOAD on the Oracle (Java) provided libjsig.so, this is supposedly required to correctly install custom signal handlers when using JNI (and if not done, other test cases fail).

Strangely, if I run the test without the LD_PRELOAD, the signal handler does get invoked for this case.

Looking for ideas on how to debug or solve this problem

Comment: Without `LD_PRELOAD` it works.. You do it and it doesn't work.. Sounds like the library you're loading has issues.

Comment: Handling SIGSEGV might be painful :( Java uses it internally for exceptions. Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-015/ However, you still will face issues in case you have multithread based application (Java) that throws exceptions :(

Comment: You can look at something called: "Signal Chaining" and using library libjsig http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/signals-139944.html

Comment: Yes, Brandon, the library apparently has issues, that's kind of the point, but trying to figure out a solution regardless.

Comment: MKO, we are using Signal Chaining and libjsig, that was described in the original posting

Answer (score 3):

When I had to write JNI code to handle `SIGSEGV` *et al* - I had code that had to clean up some file state on abnormal termination - I found it easier to just manually chain a `SIGABRT` handler and not use `libjsig.so` at all.  The JVM always seemed to terminate abnormally with a `SIGABRT` - I'd cause a fatal `SIGSEGV`, which the JVM would handle and translate to a `SIGABRT`.  It didn't seem to matter what I did.

I can't find it in the Oracle documentation right now, but [IBM documents JVM signal handling thus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.80.doc/user/sighand.html):

> **Errors**
>
> The JVM raises a `SIGABRT` if it detects a condition from which it cannot recover.

A version of my code (abbreviated in order to eliminate the scroll bar):

```
typedef void ( *sigaction_handler_t )( int, siginfo_t *, void * );
static sigaction_handler_t original_sigabort_handler = NULL;

static void handler( int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *arg )
{
    switch ( sig )
    {
    case SIGABRT:
        //do stuff - stack trace, setrlimit() to generate core file, etc.
        if ( NULL != original_sigabort_handler )
        {
            original_sigabort_handler( sig, info, arg );
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

__attribute(( constructor )) void library_init_code( void )
{
    struct sigaction new_act, old_act;
    memset( &new_act, 0, sizeof( new_act );
    memset( &old_act, 0, sizeof( old_act );
    sigemptyset( &( new_act.sa_mask ) );
    new_act.sa_sigaction = handler;
    new_act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    sigaction( SIGABRT, &new_act, &old_act );
    if ( ( old_act.sa_sigaction != ( sigaction_handler_t ) SIG_IGN ) &&
         ( old_act.sa_sigaction != ( sigaction_handler_t ) SIG_DFL ) )
    {
        original_sigabort_handler = old_act.sa_sigaction;
    }
}
```